# PHP DOM with namespace - parsing custom tags in a HTML template

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

My goal is to create a custom templating system for HTML documents in PHP. I'm using DOMDocument, but I'm having trouble getting it to recognize a custom namespace for special tags I want to introduce.

The beginning of my test script looks like this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML('
        <div>
            <example:content />
        </div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$elements = $document->getElementsByTagNameNS('example', 'content');
```

When run I get the following warning. I don't mind suppressing it if I can get the namespace to work.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag example:content invalid in Entity, line: 3 in /Users/ryanwilliams/Sites/Test XML/test.php on line 8
```

When I `var_dump` `$elements` I get the following output (it found no results).

```
object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

When I `echo` the parsed template I get the following results. Note that it stripped out the namespace.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<div>
            <content></content>
        </div>
```

Anyone know what I need to do to get it to recognize the namespace for that element?

Comment: Upon further research, it looks like the `loadHTML` method always strips out namespaces. But the `loadXML` method is too strict for parsing HTML templates (especially when I'm not necessarily the one writing them). So unless someone has a better suggestion, it looks like I may have to use an `<example-content />' tag as opposed to '<example:content />'. Not ideal, but if anyone has a different solution I'd be thrilled.

Comment: Why not using XHTML? That would be strict/valid enough to use loadXml().

Comment: @ThW I wish I could. If it was just me using it, it wouldn't be a problem because I write valid XHTML anyhow. But my plan is to provide this templating system to designers who are not going to like it when the templating system yells at them for invalid markup.

Comment: HTML5 custom templates **require** there to be a hyphen, so your best bet is to follow the example-content route. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements